# how to add List values into combobox

Tags: list, combobox, addition

I have two forms, one if for adding a person , the other one is for Removing.

(btw please ignore the var s written in other language)

!st form : personnel adding

There are 4 textboxes and 1 button to add values.

```
  public partial class PersonelAddForm : Form
{

    public PersonelAddForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    List<Personel> persListesi;
    public PersonelRemoveForm anaform;

    private void btnPersonelEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        persListesi = new List<Personel>()
        {
       new Personel {PersonelID= txtPerID.Text, Isim = txtPerIsim.Text, Soyisim =txtPerSoyisim.Text,           DeptIsmi = txtPerDeptIsmi.Text}  
        };


        anaform.cbPersonelRemove.Items.AddRange(persListesi);


    }
}
```

2nd form : personnel removing

there is just one combobox names cbPersonelRemove.

So the problem is, if i added my personnels into the List , 
    I cannot pass these values into the combobox that i have on 2nd form by doing

```
    anaform.cbPersonelRemove.Items.AddRange(persListesi);
```

Could you help this newbie please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if cbPersonelRemove public? please provide more info.
you may also do it as:

```
 anaform.cbPersonelRemove.Items.Add(new Personel {PersonelID= txtPerID.Text, Isim = txtPerIsim.Text, Soyisim =txtPerSoyisim.Text,           DeptIsmi = txtPerDeptIsmi.Text});
```

Comment: Hi, yes it is public, and because of that I can see it in first form.

the reason why I am using List because im still learning those, and trying to develop myself by using different controls together.

btw, thank you for ur quick reply.